# Jquery attr('checked') issue

Tags: jquery

Hello guys i'm beginner at JS/jQuery, i'm having problem with adding checked attribute to input.

```js
$(".switch-label-2").click(function () {
    var span = $(this).parent().siblings('#reminderstatus');
    var status = span.html().trim() == "OFF" ? "ON" : "OFF";
    var color = span.html() == "ON" ? "#a2a2a2" : "#89c12d";
    span.html(status);
    span.css('color', color);
    console.log(status);
    if (status == "ON") {
        $("#switch-2").attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#switch-2").attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.remindertoggle {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#reminderstatus {
    color: #a2a2a2;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.switch-label-2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 24px;
    text-indent: -150%;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

    .switch-label-2:before,
    .switch-label-2:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .switch-label-2:before {
        width: 100%;
        height: 24px;
        background-color: #dedede;
        border-radius: 9999em;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
        transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
    }

    .switch-label-2:after {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        /*background-color: #fff;*/
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
        -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
        transition: left 0.25s ease;
    }

.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-2:before {
    background-color: #89c12d;
}

.switch-input:checked + .switch-label-2:after {
    left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
    <div class="remindertoggle">
        <span id="reminderstatus">OFF</span>                                         
        <div id="switch" class="switch">                                      
            <input id="switch-2" type="checkbox" class="switch-input">                                      <label for="switch-2" class="switch-label-2">Switch</label>   
        </div>                                  
    </div> 
</div>
```

You will notice when i click toggle label everything got change as needs to be except one thing , on first click it add attribute check to input put it doesn't check the chekbox for real.

I'm confused couldn't solve this all day , i've googled around and couldn't find the answer.

Further thanks for any information and suggestions.

Comment: `.prop('checked',true)`

Comment: have you consoled logged inside your conditional statements to make sure it reaches the `.attr('checked')`? also you can try `.attr('checked', 'checked')`

Comment: The checkbox appears to be checked when "OFF" and unchecked when "ON"

Comment: Yes because on the first click something gone wrong and doesn't check on 1st click :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version fixes the appearance (hiding the underlying checkbox), the colours of the switch appear correctly every time, and also uses the .prop() method to set the property correctly, as described in the jQuery documentation (see http://api.jquery.com/attr/). A couple of other minor things are also tidied up / simplified.

```js
$(".switch-label-2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var span = $('#reminderstatus');
  var status = span.text().trim() == "OFF" ? "ON" : "OFF";
  var color = status == "OFF" ? "#a2a2a2" : "#89c12d";
  span.html(status);
  span.css('color', color);
  if (status == "ON") {
    $("#switch-2").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $("#switch-2").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.remindertoggle {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#reminderstatus {
  color: #a2a2a2;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch-label-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  text-indent: -150%;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.switch-label-2:before,
.switch-label-2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-label-2:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 9999em;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

.switch-label-2:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background-color: #fff;*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}

.switch-input:checked+.switch-label-2:before {
  background-color: #89c12d;
}

.switch-input:checked+.switch-label-2:after {
  left: 30px;
}

#switch-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="remindertoggle">
    <span id="reminderstatus">OFF</span>
    <div id="switch" class="switch">
      <input id="switch-2" type="checkbox" class="switch-input"> <label for="switch-2" class="switch-label-2">Switch</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx man but i need to add checked="checked" to my input when input is checked is that possible , thats what im looking for

Comment: That's what .prop() is doing for you. It sets the "checked" property of the checkbox. Note that you don't need to set the attribute, just the property. Think of the attribute as something read only, to be used only when initialising the page. The property is what gets used when submitting forms etc

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `prop(...)` function to check and set the appropriate values.

You should also prevent the event from bubbling with `preventDefault` as this was causing the weirdness on first click.

```js
$(".switch-label-2").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var isOn = $("#switch-2").prop('checked');

  // flip text status
  $('#reminderstatus').text(isOn ? "OFF" : "ON");
  
  // flip checked status
  $("#switch-2").prop('checked', !isOn);
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.remindertoggle {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#reminderstatus {
  color: #a2a2a2;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch-label-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
  text-indent: -150%;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.switch-label-2:before,
.switch-label-2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-label-2:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 9999em;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

.switch-label-2:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*background-color: #fff;*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}

.switch-input:checked+.switch-label-2:before {
  background-color: #89c12d;
}

.switch-input:checked+.switch-label-2:after {
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

  <div class="remindertoggle">
    <span id="reminderstatus">OFF</span>
    <div id="switch" class="switch">
      <input id="switch-2" type="checkbox" class="switch-input">
      <label for="switch-2" class="switch-label-2">Switch</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great , preventDefault(); , i forgot to try this :D thx champion !!

Comment: @zoneqt not to be rude but how is this the better answer? Mine fixes the visual glitches as well, but otherwise performs the same tasks. This also uses the ".prop()" method you were asking about

Comment: Phuzi - small thing, but `$(this).parent().siblings('#reminderstatus')` is pointless since "reminderstatus" is already an ID, it must necessarily be unique (or it should be). `$("#reminderstatus")` should be sufficient to select it, without running unnecessary DOM traversals

Comment: Guys thank you all , you all helped me i appreciate your help, i owe you the beer